# Settng PHP cookies while using custom header for Apache Indexes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cookies

I've searched everywhere, but was not able to find any info on this.

Here is the situation:

I am using a PHP file as "HeaderName" for my webspace:

.htaccess has the following:

```
Options +Indexes
HeaderName /.resource/header.php
```

in header.php I am including (first thing, before echoing any data) a small include that checks for presence of a parameter and sets a cookie:

```
if (isset($_GET['css_style']) && $_GET['css_style'] != "") {
  $css_style = $_GET['css_style'];
  if (setcookie('css_style', $css_style, 0, "/", "xxx.xxxx.xxx") !== false) {
    echo "<!-- cookie set! ".$css_style." -->";
  } else {
    echo "<!-- cookie NOT set! ".$css_style." -->";
  }
}
```

Now, I am using this snippet in other PHP pages on the same site, in any directory, the cookie always get set when I expect it to. It is listed in the Browser's cookie list and contains the desired value.

**However**, when the same script gets executed as part of the automatic indexing in header.php, I get the "cookie set" output, so I know that the correct conditions all apply, but the cookie is not present in the Browser's cookie list. if I call header.php *directly*, then the cookie gets set and is present on the browser's list.

**So my question:** Does Apache do something that might prevent a cookie from being dropped? The site is running on Apache in a hosted environment, but I don't have access to the central server config.

I've tried various different ways to set the cookie, with defaults, with an expire of 0 or time() + 3600*24, with and without a path and domain, no luck. I'm stumped. Especially since it works with a regular file placed in the same directory as the index I am looking at.

Comment: In that circumstance, is there output sent before the setcookie() call? Turn on display_errors.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also, what automatic indexing are you referring to?

Comment: Hi, I do not know what the apache webserver does, but none of my scripts sends any output before setting the cookie.

Also, the script does not return an error when setting the cookie, as it would IF there was any output written (I tested this also)

By automatic indexing I meant the "Options +Indexes" functionality, where an index file is generated by Apache if it is missing from a given directory

Comment: I will try the error-reporting - I did not know about this!

Comment: I understand now. So it is Apache's directory index screen you are concerned with. I don't have much experience with it, as it is usually the first thing I turn off.

Comment: Yes, that is it. The file is designated as header for this index works fine on its own, just not when used with the index

Comment: error-reporting gave no new clues (none are displayed). Sooo I am still stumped.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://anaaman.blogspot.com/2006/06/headername-and-php-scripts-execution.html  If you look at the page source of the index , are you seeing the PHP code in there (as though it was not parsed)

Comment: THanks for your help so far! I've already learned new things about PHP. Unfortunately, that is not it either. I had added this content-type already, and in my case the php does get parsed. There is only HTML in the page source. But I suspect that somewhere there may be the heart of the issue. I still do not know what to do about it other than implement my own directory-index files for each of my subfolders. Which I was trying to avoid. (The auto index greatly reduces the number of files to maintain, which is what I want here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to decide by to Query Params if you want to sent a cookie
The mod_index creates text/* but no headers

You can use mod_headers for sending cookies:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html

and mod_setenfif for conditional sending:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this of course explains the problem I was having! Unfortunately I do not have access to apache config. I've since solved this by writing my own index.php